# c - queue implimintation

Tags: c, pointers, queue, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include "Mission6.h"
/************************************************************************
* function name:MissionSix
* input:none
* output:none
* operation:gets a choice from the user makes a menu to choose from.
*************************************************************************/ 
void MissionSix(){
    static int queueTail=0,queueHead=0,amountOfTimes=0; //so their values stay throughout the program.
    //amountOfItems represents the amount of times i used the functionAddItemToQueue
    int choice;
    int **queue=NULL;
    PrintMenu();
    do{
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 0: 
                return;
            case 1:
                AddItemToQueue(queue,&queueHead,&queueTail,&amountOfTimes);
                break;
            case 2:
                RemoveItemFromQueue(queue,&queueHead,&queueTail);
                break;
            case 3:
                PrintQueue(queue,&queueHead,&queueTail);
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8: 
                PrintMenu();
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error: Unrecognized choice\n");
        }
        printf("Please select your next choice (select 8 for complete menu)\n");
    } //end of "do"
    while(choice!=0);

}
/************************************************************************
* function name:printMenu
* input:none
* output:none
* operation:prints the menu.
*************************************************************************/ 
void PrintMenu(){ 
    printf("Please select your choice:\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
    printf("1. Add item to the queue\n");
    printf("2. Remove item from the queue\n");
    printf("3. Print queue\n");
    printf("4. Print the maximum item in the queue\n");
    printf("5. Print the minimum item in the queue\n");
    printf("6. Print index of given item\n");
    printf("7. Clear queue\n");
    printf("8. Print the menu\n");
}
/************************************************************************
* function name:AddItemToQueue
* input: the queue (an array of pointers), its head(integer), its tail(int) and the amount
  of times this function was called(int)
* output:none
* operation:gets an item from the user and adds it to the queue.
*************************************************************************/ 
void AddItemToQueue(int **queue,int *head,int* tail,int* amountOfTimes){
    int itemToAdd;
    printf("Enter item value to add \n");
    scanf("%d",&itemToAdd);
    queue=(int **)realloc(queue,sizeof(int*)*((*amountOfTimes)+1)); //amount of items in queue =*head - *tail
    if(queue==NULL){
        printf("Error: Insufficient Memory\n");
        return;
    }
    queue[*head]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); //builds size for the data
    if (queue[*head]==NULL){
        printf("Error: Insufficient Memory\n");
        return;
    }
    *queue[*head]=itemToAdd;//adding the item to the correct spot
    (*head)++;
    (*amountOfTimes)++;
}
/************************************************************************
* function name:RemoveItemFromQueue
* input:the queue (an array of pointers), its head(integer) and its tail(int). 
* output:none
* operation:removes first element in the queue.
*************************************************************************/ 
void RemoveItemFromQueue(int **queue,int *head, int* tail){
    if((*head)==(*tail)){ //if head and tail are equal the queue is empty.
        printf("Error: Queue is empty!\n");
        return;
    }

    free(queue[*tail]);
    (*tail)++;
}
/************************************************************************
* function name:PrintQueue
* input:the queue (an array of pointers), its head(integer) and its tail(int). 
* output:none
* operation:prints the elements of the queue
*************************************************************************/ 
void PrintQueue(int **queue,int *head, int*tail){
    int i;
    printf("Queue items are: ");
    for(i=(*tail);i<(*head);i++){
        printf("%d ",**(queue+i));
    }
}
```

what i'm trying to do is implement a queue in c: it works as a first in first it.

the problems are:

1. the function "RemoveItemFromQueue" doesn't work
2. the function "PrintQueue" doesn't work for some reason.

note that i know i haven't freed mallocs in my program, ill deal with it later.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step line-by-line through your code? This will likely allow you to easily pinpoint the nature and location of the issue you're having. If you haven't used a debugger before, you should know that using a debugger is, for all intents and purposes, required knowledge for any programmer. For more info, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `int **queue=(int **)malloc(1);` --> `int *queue=NULL;`

Comment: first of all, i changed the pastebin and added a technical specification for each function.  second of all, i changed it still doesn't work.

Comment: please post code - not links to code :-)

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: crashes the program completly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (I'm sorry if my understanding was wrong):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "Mission6.h"
void PrintMenu(void);
void AddItemToQueue(int **queue,int *head,int* tail,int* amountOfTimes);
void RemoveItemFromQueue(int **queue,int *head, int* tail);
void PrintQueue(int *queue, int head, int tail);

void MissionSix(void){
    int queueTail = 0, queueHead = 0, amountOfTimes = 0;
    //amountOfItems represents the amount of times i used the functionAddItemToQueue
    int choice;
    int *queue = NULL;
    PrintMenu();
    do{
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
        case 0:
            free(queue);
            return;
        case 1:
            AddItemToQueue(&queue, &queueHead, &queueTail, &amountOfTimes);
            break;
        case 2:
            RemoveItemFromQueue(&queue, &queueHead, &queueTail);
            break;
        case 3:
            PrintQueue(queue, queueHead, queueTail);
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;
        case 8: 
            PrintMenu();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error: Unrecognized choice\n");
        }
        printf("Please select your next choice (select 8 for complete menu)\n");
    } while(choice != 0);

}

void PrintMenu(void){ 
    fputs(
        "Please select your choice:\n"
        "0. Exit\n"
        "1. Add item to the queue\n"
        "2. Remove item from the queue\n"
        "3. Print queue\n"
        "4. Print the maximum item in the queue\n"
        "5. Print the minimum item in the queue\n"
        "6. Print index of given item\n"
        "7. Clear queue\n"
        "8. Print the menu\n",
        stdout
    );
}

void AddItemToQueue(int **queue, int *head, int *tail, int *amountOfTimes){
    int itemToAdd;
    printf("Enter item value to add \n");
    scanf("%d", &itemToAdd);
    *queue = realloc(*queue, ++*amountOfTimes * sizeof(int));
    if(*queue == NULL){
        printf("Error: Insufficient Memory\n");
        return;
    }
    (*queue)[(*tail)++] = itemToAdd;
}

void RemoveItemFromQueue(int **queue, int *head, int *tail){
//if restructure queue, need int *amountOfTimes
    if( *head == *tail){
        printf("Error: Queue is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    ++*head;
}

void PrintQueue(int *queue, int head, int tail){
    int i;
    printf("Queue items are: ");
    for(i = head; i < tail; ++i){
        printf("%d ", queue[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(void){
    MissionSix();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution is much simpler, i now realize it was much simpler to use a single pointer instead of two, thank you.